# Why does my custom WordPress side cart plugin close automatically?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I recently made a custom plugin for wordpress and it is a side cart which opens on clicking a floating button and shows cart content but it keeps closing automatically just after opening it

I have 3 files sidemenu-plugin.php, style.css and script.js it should update via ajax and update the cart contents without having to refresh but it automatically closes just after opening it.

sidemenu-plugin.php code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Floating Side Cart
Description: Adds a floating button that opens a side menu on click
Version: 1.0
Author: Swaraj Singh
*/


// Add the settings page to the admin dashboard
function sidemenu_settings_page() {
  add_menu_page(
    'Sidemenu Settings',
    'Sidemenu Settings',
    'manage_options',
    'sidemenu-settings',
    'sidemenu_settings_page_callback'
  );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'sidemenu_settings_page');


// Add the settings page HTML
function sidemenu_settings_page_callback() {
  ?>
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Sidemenu Settings</h1>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
      <?php settings_fields('sidemenu_settings'); ?>
      <?php do_settings_sections('sidemenu_settings'); ?>
      <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
          <br>
          <h3><b>Color Settings</b></h1>
          <th scope="row">Background Color:</th>
          <td><input type="color" name="sidemenu_background_color" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('sidemenu_background_color')); ?>" /></td>
          <th scope="row">Text Color:</th>
          <td><input type="color" name="sidemenu_text_color" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('sidemenu_text_color')); ?>" /></td>
          <th scope="row">View Cart Text Color:</th>
          <td><input type="color" name="sidemenu_vc_text_color" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('sidemenu_vc_text_color')); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php
}

// Register the settings with WordPress
function sidemenu_register_settings() {
  register_setting('sidemenu_settings', 'sidemenu_background_color');
  register_setting('sidemenu_settings', 'sidemenu_text_color');
  register_setting('sidemenu_settings', 'sidemenu_vc_text_color');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'sidemenu_register_settings');


function add_sidemenu_button() {
  global $woocommerce;
  $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

  // Get the background color from the options
  $background_color = get_option('sidemenu_background_color');
  $text_color = get_option('sidemenu_text_color');
  $vc_text_color = get_option('sidemenu_vc_text_color');

  // Add the button HTML
  echo '<button id="sidemenu-button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>';

  // Add the menu or empty cart message HTML
  if (empty($items)) {
    echo '<div id="sidemenu" style="background-color: ' . $background_color . '">';
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message" style="color: ' . $text_color . '">';
    echo 'Your cart is currently empty.';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
  } else {
    $cart_content = '<div id="sidemenu" style="background-color: ' . $background_color . '; color: ' . $text_color . '">';
    foreach($items as $item => $values) {
      $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());
      $cart_content .= "<b>".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>';
      $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
      $cart_content .= "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
      $cart_content .= '<a href="' . wc_get_cart_remove_url( $item ) . '" style="color: ' . $vc_text_color . '">Remove</a><br>';
    }
    $cart_content .= '<br><a href="' . wc_get_cart_url() . '" style="color: ' . $vc_text_color . '">View Cart</a></div>'; // Add View Cart button
    echo '<div id="cart-sidebar">';
    echo $cart_content;
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
  

// Add the button and menu to the page
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_sidemenu_button');

// Add the CSS and JavaScript files
function add_sidemenu_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('sidemenu-style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('sidemenu-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    

    // Localize the AJAX URL
  wp_localize_script(
    'sidemenu-script',
    'ajax_object',
    array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
  );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_sidemenu_scripts');

// AJAX callback function to update cart content
function update_cart_content_ajax_callback() {
  ob_start(); // Start output buffering

  // Move the code from add_sidemenu_button() here
  global $woocommerce;
  $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

  // Get the background color from the options
  $background_color = get_option('sidemenu_background_color');
  $text_color = get_option('sidemenu_text_color');
  $vc_text_color = get_option('sidemenu_vc_text_color');

  // Add the menu or empty cart message HTML
  if (empty($items)) {
    echo '<div id="sidemenu" style="background-color: ' . $background_color . '">';
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message" style="color: ' . $text_color . '">';
    echo 'Your cart is currently empty.';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
  } else {
    $cart_content = '<div id="sidemenu" style="background-color: ' . $background_color . '; color: ' . $text_color . '">';
    foreach($items as $item => $values) {
      $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());
      $cart_content .= "<b>".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>';
      $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
      $cart_content .= "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
      $cart_content .= '<a href="' . wc_get_cart_remove_url( $item ) . '" style="color: ' . $vc_text_color . '">Remove</a><br>';
    }
    $cart_content .= '<br><a href="' . wc_get_cart_url() . '" style="color: ' . $vc_text_color . '">View Cart</a></div>'; // Add View Cart button
    echo '<div id="cart-sidebar">';
    echo $cart_content;
    echo '</div>';
  }

  $response = ob_get_clean(); // Get the buffered content

  echo $response; // Send the cart content back as the AJAX response

  wp_die(); // Terminate AJAX request
}


// Hook the AJAX callback function
add_action('wp_ajax_update_cart_content', 'update_cart_content_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_cart_content', 'update_cart_content_ajax_callback');
```

style.css code

```
#sidemenu-button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#sidemenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -300px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 9998;
}

#sidemenu.open {
    right: 0;
}
```

script.js code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Add click event listener to the button
  $('#sidemenu-button').on('click', function(e) {
    // Toggle the class on the menu to open/close it
    $('#sidemenu').toggleClass('open');
    updateCartContent(); // Call the function to update cart content
  });

  // Close cart sidebar if user clicks outside of it
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var container = $('#sidemenu');
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 && container.css('right') === '0px') {
      container.toggleClass('open');
    }
  });

  // Prevent clicks inside the cart sidebar from closing it
  $('#sidemenu').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  function updateCartContent() {
    $.ajax({
      url: ajax_object.ajax_url, // The AJAX URL
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: 'update_cart_content' // AJAX action hook
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#sidemenu').replaceWith(response); // Replace the entire cart sidebar with the updated content
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Because directly after you added the `open` class, you call `updateCartContent` - which replaces the whole `#sidemenu` with the content loaded from the server. And in that content, the `#sidemenu` element does not have the class `open`.